# Where can I find more wallpaper packages?

Tags: desktop-background

I was wondering if there are any wallpaper packages around. Packages with loads of wallpapers which are as good as the pre-installed ones. Anything close?

Comment: Couldn't find anything to try.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Picture_of_the_Year

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you get bored of downloading a lot of wallpapers packages and still in search of some more then **[Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/) will quench your thirst**

**Installing Variety**

- open terminal by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute these commands to add repository and install it.

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install variety
  ```
- Then open `variety` from *Dash*
- And get started to dig a lot of features. More you dig more features and wallpaper you'll get.
- I have been using it for a very long time and fully satisfied. Could not find any better than this. Thanks to [Peter Levi!](https://plus.google.com/111758109475195528754/photos?banner=pwa)
- [See more about variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/about-variety/)

[image]

[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]
[image: image5]

<sub>[Source: peterlevi.com/variety/](http://peterlevi.com/variety/)</sub>

Answer (score 9):

> I was wondering if there are any wallpaper packages around

Sure, quite a lot actually. They can be found in your package management like any other package.

> wallpapers which are as good as the pre-installed ones

Is a really subjective requirement and there's no definite single answer to your question because of this.

Obvious things to try from here: Use the `wallpaper` and/or `background` keywords in...

- finding high-rated listings in the Software Center.
- searching on [`packages.ubuntu.com`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) or by issuing `apt-cache search wallpaper background` on the command-line.

Make sure the `universe` and `multiverse` repositories are enabled for a wider set of artwork. Feel free to try out any package and remove the ones you don't like.